# Remove Domain Association; Domain controller no longer exists

Tags: windows-7, domain

I have a Win 7 computer for work. The company was acquired and the original domain controller no longer exists. In fact, we don't use a domain controller at all.

Does having a non-exist domain association on a computer impact performance at all and if so, how do I remove the association.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the computer from the domain, you'll need access to a **local** administrator account. This may be as easy as typing `.\Administrator` in the `Username:` field at login and pushing enter. If the account is disabled or has a password that you do not know, then you'll need to use [some](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) [kind](http://trinityhome.org) [of](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) [boot](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html) [CD](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html) to gain access to it.

As for the performance issue, it's hard to say. It really depends on how that particular domain was configured and what kind of group policies were applied to the machine. For example, if it's still looking for a user profile on a network share that no longer exists, then yeah, you may run in to some odd behavior or even temporary profiles. Basically you're opening yourself to a lot of unknowns.

I would definitely remove the machine from the domain.

Comment: I think Control Panel\System and Security\System; then 'Change settings' would be the place to try.  I agree, there is no downside to removing this computer from a non-existent domain.

Comment: Using the "system properties" method, it's telling me I can remove the domain but I will need to know the password to the local admin account. I just re-set that password (so User "Administrator" has a password I know) and then my normal user account password is known to me. Is the normal user account going to be remove when I do this or will the user just revert to a Win7 Work group user.

Comment: r.tanner.f and Guy, thank you for the info. Despite the add'l question it's light years ahead of where I was. So, again, thank you.