# How to disable/remove some of global domain policies

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

My laptop used to connect to company domain server, so it inherited from the global domain policy. Now I no longer have this laptop connect to the company domain, and would like to change the password policy settings (e.g. max/min pwd characters, password complexity). However, in gpedit.msc, the password settings are all greyed out.

How do I make it editable again in `gpedit.msc`? I know these settings would be overwritten by domain server once connecting to it again. Though like I said, I won't use this laptop connect to company network anymore.

Comment: Do you have a local account in the computer ? if yes then you must un-join your computer from domain and then remove .sdb files and registry keys. a domain administrator password is also must sotaht you can  authenticate the un-join activity

Comment: I have local account, but don't have domain admin pwd. In that case, is it still possible to proceed?

Comment: Also see: [Remove Domain Association; Domain controller no longer exists](http://superuser.com/questions/536607/remove-domain-association-domain-controller-no-longer-exists)

Comment: I usually remove the computer from domain, login with a local admin account and remove the registry keys and remove secedit.sdb file. You can try to remove the registry keys and .sdb files but i am not sure how effective that would be or if there would be complications as i have no first hand experience of your situation

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I actually found that post earlier. However, I don't want to remove all the group policies set by domain server. Most of them improves the security for my system. I just wanted to remove the password policies. That's why my question is "disable/remove some domain policies". This should not be a duplicate one.